# How can I reference a value from a different module?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-aws-modules

I want to deploy an RDS database to AWS with a secret from AWS Secrets Manager. I have:

```
├─ environments
│   └─ myenv
│       ├── main.tf
│       ├── locals.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└─ modules
    ├─ db
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
    └─ secrets
        └── main.tf
```

In `myenv/main.tf` I define a module `mydb` that has `modules/db/main.tf` as `source` where a resource database is defined. Save for the password it all works, I specify values in blocks in `myenv` and the values "trickle down".
But for the credentials, I don't want to hard code them in `myenv` of course.
Instead in  `modules/secrets` I define

```
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "my_credentials" {
  # Fill in the name you gave to your secret
  secret_id = "my-secret-id"
}
```

and with another block:

```
locals {
  decoded_secrets = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.my_credentials.secret_string)
}
```

I decode the secrcets and now I want to reference them as e.g. `local.decoded_secrets.username` in `myenv/main`. That is my interpretation of the tutorials. But it doesn't work: If I put the `locals` block in `myenv` it cannot reference `data`, and when I put it in `modules/secrets` then `myenv` cannot reference `locals`.
How can I combine the values of these two modules in my `myenv/main`?

Comment: Is there a reason that the secret needs to be in a separate module instead of part of the `db` module? That would simplify it a lot.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR There are actually several db instances, each with their own secret, so I figured I better separate the concerns into their own modules and coordinate from `myenv`. But I suppose I could merge them.

Comment: Your `db` module still creates a single database right? And you aren't sharing secrets between those databases too right? In which case it seems much cleaner to collapse the `secrets` module here into the `db` module.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR my db module defines a single database resource and there is no secret sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a few options available to you here to pass the secret to the database module.

The smallest thing you need to do from your existing setup would be to call both modules at the same time and pass an output from the secrets module to the database module like this:

```
.
├── environments
│   └── myenv
│       ├── locals.tf
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└── modules
    ├── db
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   └── variables.tf
    └── secrets
        ├── main.tf
        └── outputs.tf
```

#### modules/secrets/outputs.tf

```
output "secret_id" {
  value = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secret.secret_id
}
```

#### environments/myenv/main.tf

```
module "secrets" {
  source = "../../modules/secrets"
  # ...
}

module "db" {
  source    = "../../modules/db"
  # ...
  secret_id = module.secrets.secret_id
}
```

A better approach however might be to have the database module create and manage its own secret and not require the secret to be passed into the database module as a parameter at all. If you wanted to reuse the secrets module with other modules then you could make it a child module of the database module or if this is the only place you currently use the secrets module then unnesting these makes things simpler.

### Nesting modules

#### modules/db/main.tf

```
module "database_password_secret_id" {
  source = "../secrets"
  # ...
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "database_password" {
  secret_id = module.database_password_secret_id.secret_id
}
```

### Unnesting the modules

```
.
├── environments
│   └── myenv
│       ├── locals.tf
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── variables.tf
└── modules
    └── db
        ├── main.tf
        ├── secrets.tf
        └── variables.tf
```

#### modules/db/secrets.tf

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "database_password" {
  name = "database-password"
}

resource "random_password" "database_password" {
  length = 32
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "database_password" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.example.id
  secret_string = random_password.database_password.result
}
```

#### modules/db/main.tf

```
resource "aws_db_instance" "database" {
  # ...
  password = aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.database_password.secret_string
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Define an [output](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/outputs.html) in the `secrets` module. Define an [input](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html) in the `db` module. Pass the output value from `secrets` to the input property in `db`.

For example if you defined an output named "password" in `secrets` and an input named "password" in `db`, then in your db module declaration you would pass the value like this:

```
module "secrets" {
  source = "../modules/secrets"
}

module "db" {
  source = "../modules/db"
  password = module.secrets.password

}
```

Comment: While this answers the question if you'd looked at the comments on the question you'd see that there's an easier way to do this by collapsing the secret module into the database module here because they don't need them to be composed separately. If they'd needed the secrets module for other modules as well then they could have also called the secrets module as a child module of the database module and still had a better outcome than this, providing a cleaner API to their database module.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I don't consider that "better" or "cleaner", just different. My answer is actually a very common pattern I've seen in lots of Terraform code. 1. It gives you the option of managing the password inside Terraform, or through some other means completely outside of terraform. 2. The DB password usually needs to be passed to other things, like the applications that will be connecting to the database, so it is extremely common to need that value outside of the DB module.

Comment: That can definitely be the case for modules where you have less control over how they are used (eg ones on the Terraform Registry) but where you are writing your own modules for internal use you can simplify the interface to the module by having the module handle things in the way you expect (eg it creates resources directly inside it or where they need to be managed externally then you pass it a human readable thing that the module uses with a data source to fetch the ID rather than making the caller specify a data source every time). Here the OP suggests an easier pattern available to them.